# What is the correct way to store and print a character in MIPS?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I writing a simple program to reverse the case of characters that the user inputs and it prints out the reversed string and the lowest character in the new string (according to it's ASCII value). The issue arises when I try to print the character. I can see that a value is retained in register $s1, but printing the character yields a box instead of any actual character, and if I try to print it as a string it simply prints as an empty line.

Here is my program:

```
main:   
#
# system call to prompt user for input
#
     la $a0,outpPrompt  # system call 4 for print string needs address of string in $a0
     li $v0,4       # system call 4 for print string needs 4 in $v0
     syscall    
#
# system call to store user input into string thestring
#
    li $v0,8        # system call 8 for read string needs its call number 8 in $v0
                    # get return values
    la $a0,varStr       # put the address of thestring buffer in $t0
    li $a1,32           # maximum length of string to load
        syscall
#
# system call to display "You entered the string: "
#
     la $a0,outpStr     # system call 4 for print string needs address of string in $a0
     li $v0,4       # system call 4 for print string needs 4 in $v0
     syscall    

     la $a0,varStr      # system call 4 for print string needs address of string in $a0
     li $v0,4       # system call 4 for print string needs 4 in $v0
     syscall

    jal revCase     # Invoking revCase, string stored in $a0 printed

# Exit gracefully from main()
         li   $v0, 10       # system call for exit
         syscall            # close file

revCase:
    
    la $t1, varStr      # Loading user input
    la $t2, varStrRev   # Designated output string
    
    revLoop:
        lb $t0, 0($t1)      # loads char of $t1 into $t0
        beqz $t0, doneRev       # when 0 is hit, ends the loop
        
        blt $t0, 'A', saveChar  # if $t0 < A then saveChar
        ble $t0, 'Z', lowerCase # if $t0 >= A and <= Z jump to lowerCase
        blt $t0, 'a', saveChar  # if $t0 < a then saveChar
        ble $t0, 'z', upperCase # if $t0 >= a and <= z jump to upperCase
        j saveChar      # if $t0 > z then saveChar
        
        upperCase:
        subi $t0, $t0, 32   # converts uppercase letter to lowercase letter
        j saveChar
        
        lowerCase:
        addi $t0, $t0, 32   # converts lowercase letter to uppercase letter
        j saveChar
        
        saveChar:
        sb $t0, 0($t2)      # character saved to $t2
        
        addi $t1, $t1, 1    # increment input
        addi $t2, $t2, 1    # increment output
        
    j revLoop           # continues the loop
    
    doneRev:
    sb $zero, 0($t2)    # adds a 0 to end of string
    la $v0, varStrRev   # Stores address of converted string into $v0

#
# This is the system call to display "Your string in reverse case is: "
     la $a0,outpStrRev  # system call 4 for print string needs address of string in $a0
     li $v0,4       # system call 4 for print string needs 4 in $v0
     syscall    
# system call to display the user input that is in reverse case saved in the varRevStr buffer
     la $a0,varStrRev   # system call 4 for print string needs address of string in $a0
     li $v0,4       # system call 4 for print string needs 4 in $v0
     syscall    

    move $s0, $ra
    jal findMin     # calls findMin, replaces $ra value

jr $s0          # Return to original function call address

findMin:
    la $t1, varStrRev       # Loading reverse input
    la $s1, varStrMin       # Designated output string
    
    minLoop:
        lb $t0, 0($t1)      # setting $t0 to first char of $t1
        beqz $t0, doneMin       # break loop when $t0 = 0
        
        blt $t0, $s1, lowestChar    # if current char < saved char, jump to lowestChar
        j nextChar      # if current char >= lowest char, jump to nextChar
        
        lowestChar:
        sb $t0, 0($s1)      # save lowest char to $s1
        j nextChar
        
        nextChar:
        addi $t1, $t1, 1    # increment to next char

    j minLoop           #continue loop
    doneMin:
#
# system call to display "The min ASCII character after reversal is:  "
     la $a0, outpStrMin     # system call 4 for print string needs address of string in $a0
     li $v0, 4      # system call 4 for print string needs 4 in $v0
     syscall    

    la $a0, varStrMin
    li $v0, 11  
    syscall

jr $ra              # Return to address in revCase
```

I have tried printing using both syscall 4 & 11. I have watched the assembler in real-time to ensure that a value is being stored in register $s1. The first loop properly prints out the inverted string, so I know that these values are correct. I have tested the loop in findMin() to make sure it is running the appropriate number of times instead of exiting early. I have exhausted my knowledge of anything that could possibly be wrong. My thought is that the value is correctly stored but I am accessing it incorrectly. Any help in understanding where the program is breaking would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are storing your minima in `varStrMin` but then try to print it from `outpStrMin`. You should also initialize `varStrMin` with an approrpiate value (`0xFF`)

Comment: I first print outpStrMin, a string to preface the output, then I also make a syscall in the next 3 lines to attempt to print varStrMin. Unless I'm missing something, I believe I print both

Comment: I saw it now. Then check if you are initializing the contents of varStrMin with an appropriate value

Comment: and it seems you forgot to actually read the contents of `$s1` in `findMin` to get the current minimum found. ( check that `blt $t0, $s1, lowestChar` does is not what you want to compare)

Comment: That's a ton of code.  You should narrow it down to the part that isn't working for you.  You don't need to debug in the context of your complete program, you can experiment with small piece parts, get each of those working, then stitch back together.  For example, if you have a function or section that needs an input string, you don't have to get it from the user or from a file, you can simply hard-code some string in a small test program for that section.

Comment: On another note, you should single step debug after writing every few lines — never wait until the code is completed to start debugging.  That way, you'll know for sure what's not working: the latest few lines of code.  It is much easier that way, because as you debug and learn things, it will affect the rest of the code you'll be writing.

Comment: With MARS/QtSpim, you can use single character input & output, or string input & output, or a mix of the two, of course.  For single character input syscall#12 returns a character from the user in register `$v0`.  For single character output syscall#11 prints a character that you've put into `$a0`.

Comment: For string input syscall#8 stores a string read in from the user into memory at the location you specify in the `$a0` parameter.  You'll get a null terminated character string at the location you specify, but there'll also be a newline character right before the null, so if you don't want that newline you'll have to look out for it.  For string output, syscall#4 will print a string from memory whose address is provided by you in `$a0` parameter register.  The string you have in memory must be null terminated in the usual way for C-style strings.

Comment: Since in general the concept of strings is that they can have differing lengths, they are necessarily stored in memory as most other variable length data structures.  You can work with C-style strings, or keep a count of the length of the string somewhere (maybe in a CPU register), sometimes we do both: keep a count so we know immediately where the end is, but also null terminate the string so that they remain C-style strings ready for printing with syscall#4.

Comment: If you reuse a global data buffer for string, be aware that the first time it is used, it will be filled with nulls, but the next time, if the string in question in the buffer is shorter than last time, the buffer will not naturally null terminate, you'll have to ensure that programmatically.

Comment: You can also keep pointers instead of counters, i.e. a pointer to the current end of string.